# Passing a Linked List (incompatible pointer type error)

Tags: c, linked-list

I am getting the following error when I try to call the function that should initialize my linked list.

```
 passing argument 1 of 'init_list' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  init_list(list);
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error. This is my first time working with linked lists so any help is appreciated.
Here is how I set up my linked list along with the prototype for my function:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char DATA_TYPE;


typedef struct node_t
{
    DATA_TYPE item;
    struct node_t* next;
} node;

typedef struct
{
    node* head;
    int len;
} linkedlist_t;

void init_list(linkedlist_t* plist);
```

This is the function:

```
void init_list(linkedlist_t* plist)
{

    plist->head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    plist->head->next = NULL;
    plist->len = 0;
}
```

And this is how I called the function in `main`.

```
#include "linkedlist.h"

int main(void) {


    node list;

    init_list(&list);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `node list;`? That's not a list.

Comment: init_list wants linkedlist_t* object not node* object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `node` where your function expects a `linkedlist`. These two objects are not compatible, because a `node` is only a part of a `linkedlist`.

If your `init_list` function only initializes the `node` part, then you should change the signature to expect a `node` instead and maybe also rename it to `init_node` which would make the code clearer to understand for a reader.

```
void init_node(node *plist);
```

Otherwise change list to be of type `linkedlist`.

```
linkedlist_t list;

init_list(&list);
```